# database sql multiple image on content

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I want to make some blog editorial, this content contain multiple image. check this:

Table 1: blog

> id | title | content | img
>
> 1 | test | lorem | 1

Table 2:img

> id | img | img_id
>
> 1 | 1.jpg | 1
>
> 2 | 2.jpg | 1
>
> 3 | 3.jpg | 2

i get this eror.
General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

what should i do?

Comment: For which query you getting this error. Please add more details.

Comment: Cannot add foreign key constraint. foreign key img references img_id on img

Comment: Are you sure both of them are same type. Image Id as Foreign and primary key.

Comment: ya suree. already check their type.

Comment: add your models

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi oh yeah i forgot to add my model. i ll try this, thanks btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it this way:

`Blog.php` model

```
public function photos(){

   return $this->hasMany(Photo::class);
}
```

Then on your `Photo.php` model do like this:

```
public function blog(){

   return $this->belongsTo(Blog::class);
}
```

Then in your database migration files on `blod_table` add a column `photo_id` that way Laravel through the declared relationships knows the foreign key on the photo table, so you don't need to declare any foreign key on your migrations. That way you will not get the errors.

Or eventually go to database.php file and set mysql strict mode to false